# Aligning some of the columns in Excel Worksheet using Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am having trouble aligning the columns of an Excel Worksheet using xlsxWriter. For further clarity here is the data-frame

```
   Name        Employee ID      Year
John Miller    2014108          2014
Sarah Jones    2011548          2011
Jake Kenedy    2010546          2010
```

I am trying to align the Name column so that the values are on the left instead of  being centred

I tried this

```
workbook = writer.book
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_align('left')
```

However, nothing happened. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually apply the formatting the name column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Name': ['J Miller', 'S Jones', 'J Kenedy'],
                    'Employee ID': [1,2,3],
                    'Year': [2014, 2011, 2010]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('left_aligned_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Add your dataframe to the writer
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

new_format = workbook.add_format()
new_format.set_align('left')

# Apply new format to name column, which will be column C.
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 10, new_format)
writer.save()
```

Might be worth a look: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Comment: I tried the suggestion you provided. However, nothing happened except the cells got wider. The original data frame is much larger and has over 40000 entries. Furthermore, I am trying to align the index, is that causing the problem by any chance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue related to the index. My dataframe had the first column of type string as the index. It appears the index cannot be reformatted using `xlsxwriter`.
To get around this I tried the following in this order:

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
```

Then the formatting functions worked.